# How to Shrink Image Width (While Keeping It Centered) when window is resized horizontally?

Tags: html, css, resize

I was wondering how I could shrink an image when the page is resized horizontally. I tried hiding the overflow of the HEADERLINE div but it just hid the whole thing.

Here's my code so far:http://jsfiddle.net/5W2C2/4/

### HTML

```
<div id="headerline">
<img src="http://s21.postimg.org/l6t6akypj/line.jpg"/>
</div>

<div id="menu">
<img class ="blog" src="http://s18.postimg.org/il7hbk7i1/image.png">
<img class ="music" src="http://s18.postimg.org/4st2fxgqh/image.png">
<img class ="projects" src="http://s18.postimg.org/sxtrxn115/image.png">
<img class ="bio" src="http://s18.postimg.org/5xn4lb37d/image.png">
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#headerline {
    height: 1px;
    width: 980px;
    margin: -10px auto 20px auto;
}

#menu {
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}
#menu img {
    width: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I added `overflow: hidden` back in, made `width: 100%` and removed the height specified. Is this what you were aiming for?

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/5W2C2/5/